# Getting data from hundreds of data feeds and visualizing it, millisecond interval or less

Tags: market-data, charting, low-latency

Our team is working with extreme real-time charting technologies. Now we are developing web charts to visualize hundreds or even thousands of data feeds the same time. Using 1000 data points or more / second, each chart. Aiming for lowest-possible latency.

[image: 100 real-time charts with 1 ms data, programmatically generated]

Check also these video clips. Zooming of microsecond-precision data [Microsecond-level zoom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jR6Ml5bVkvc), and 400 charts scrolling video [400 charts scrolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNdbfUZwoRI)

Is there any free or paid service where we can get real-time data with 1 millisecond interval, or microsecond interval? The data feed should be arranged so that all selected stock symbols are supplied in the same feed, if possible. That would make the parsing and synchronization of different symbol easier and cause less overhead in the application.

Currently we have only been able to get this kind of data rate by generating virtual market data ourselves... Which is apparently useless in real applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could use all things listed on Binance. They list a lot of cryptocurrencies and one a lot of them also a number of derivatives. The data should be cheap to get.

Not all feeds will have new information ever second but I think a lot of them will.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommedation. We'll need to check that out.

Comment: You could use the orderbook feeds to calculate a weighted mid price. This will update more frequently than price.